# Determine if an assembly references other assemblies

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to follow the tutorial on the following webpage: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/on-the-fringe/2013/08/25/creating-and-executing-an-ssis-package-programmatically/

I have copied the following assemblies from the SQL Server 2012 machine to my development PC:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS

I have added references to the three assemblies on my local PC.  The project compiles.

Can I do this? Is there a way to see if these assemblies are self contained or if they reference other assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

You can use dependencywalker application, after install this application open the dll which you want to examine it and it will show all dependency dlls
you can find this application [Here](http://dependencywalker)